# Converting Sqlite3 Database into PostgreSQL on c9.io for existing ruby on rails app

Tags: sqlite, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, cloud9-ide

Since Heroku advises using postgres instead of sqlite, I wanted to change my database before deploying my Rails app.

Because i'm using the Cloud 9 IDE, it was suggested to me that I should start with the first two steps on this tutorial (Start the PostgreSQL service and Setting up the PostgreSQL password):

https://docs.c9.io/v1.0/docs/setting-up-postgresql

And that I should continue with these steps starting at "First, open your Gemfile":

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3#running-rails-on-postgres

The installation of the `pg` gem was successful. It then said to make some changes to `config/database.yml`. I made the suggested changes, although it was a bit different because my file came with a `default` that would seemingly carry over to other fields (this might be my problem)?

**config/database.yml**

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: my_database_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: my_database_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: my_database_production
```

However, when I do `rake db:create`, I get this error:

```
FATAL:  role "ubuntu" does not exist
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:898:in `rescue in connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:88:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:102:in `block in create_current'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:209:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:208:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:208:in `each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:101:in `create_current'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "database"=>"my_database_development"}
FATAL:  role "ubuntu" does not exist
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:898:in `rescue in connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:88:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:102:in `block in create_current'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:209:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:208:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:208:in `each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:101:in `create_current'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "pool"=>5,    "timeout"=>5000, "database"=>"my_database_test"}
```

Doing `bin/rake db:create db:migrate` (as suggested by the terminal when I tried `rake db:migrate` alone), gives me this error: `rake aborted! ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  role "ubuntu" does not exist`

trace:

```
yamilethmedina@wheels_registration:~/workspace (master) $ bin/rake db:create db:migrate
FATAL:  role "ubuntu" does not exist
Run `$ bin/rake db:create db:migrate` to create your database
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:898:in `rescue in connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:88:in `create'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:102:in `block in create_current'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:209:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:208:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:208:in `each_current_configuration'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:101:in `create_current'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/rake- 10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rake:8:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "pool"=>5,   "timeout"=>5000, "database"=>"my_database_development"}
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  role "ubuntu" does not exist
Run `$ bin/rake db:create db:migrate` to create your database
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:898:in `rescue in connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:909:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  role "ubuntu" does not exist
Run `$ bin/rake db:create db:migrate` to create your database
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:909:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:40:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:183:in `block in serve'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `fork'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `serve'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-1.2.0/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/spring-  1.2.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Strangely, it also tells me to run `bin/rake db:create db:migrate` again, even though I just did it. .

Comment: Just double checking... you are setting up production with Postgres right?  Not changing your development server.  I use SQLite for development and Postgres on Heroku for production.

Comment: @steveklein I was advised that best practice is changing to Postgres for both to lessen confusion, so that was my intention, although I could be convinced to do otherwise.

Comment: I've never tried it so maybe it is better for some reason, but I can say it was relatively straightforward to follow the Heroku instructions to deploy to PG in production.  At least an option for you if you get really stuck here.

Comment: @YamiMedina, indeed it as advised to use the same database in development and production because there are small differences between SQL databases that can cause problems. I'm not familiar with ruby but what postgres calls a role is a user so I think you forgot the specify the correct username for connecting to postgresql.

Comment: @Eelke I remember postgres telling me to create a password earlier, so that makes sense. What should I use as a username--the app name?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo sudo -u postgres <command>`

Comment: @Mutahhir this did seem to work. I was able to create and migrate my tables. i'm now having a unit socket issue when trying to restart my rails server after a few days, but that's another issue.

Comment: Ok, that's good to hear. :) Glad to be of help! Write to support@c9.io for any issues you think are due to the Cloud9 platform.